# django 404 page not found error http://localhost:8000/static/feed.html

Tags: python, mysql, django, url, azure-web-app-service

django is adding the /static/ url to my path and i don't know why

- **Page not found (404) Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/feed.html 'feed.html' could not be
  found**
- ***Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/messages.html 'messages.html' could
  not be found***
- **Page not found (404) Request Method:   GET Request
  URL: http://localhost:8000/static/upload.html 'upload.html' could not
  be found**

here is my  views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView
from app.models import SendSMS
from app.forms import SendSMSForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from app.utils import send_twilio_message
from django.conf import settings 
import datetime
# Create your views here.

# Create your models here.

def index(request): 
     return render(request, 'index.html')
def feed(request): 
     return render(request, 'feed.html')
def upload(request): 
     return render(request, 'upload.html')
def messages(request): 
    return render(request, 'messages.html')
def statistics(request): 
    return render(request, 'statistics.html')


class SendSmsCreateView(CreateView):
     model = SendSMS
     form_class = SendSMSForm
     template_name = 'messages.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('send_sms')

     def form_valid(self, form):
         number = form.cleaned_data['to_number']
         body = form.cleaned_data['body']
        # call twilio
         sent = send_twilio_message(number, body)
        # save form
        send_sms = form.save(commit=False)
        send_sms.from_number = settings.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER
        send_sms.sms_sid = sent.sid
        send_sms.account_sid = sent.account_sid
        send_sms.status = sent.status
        send_sms.sent_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        if sent.price:
            send_sms.price_unit = sent.price_unit
            send_sms.save()

        return super(SendSmsCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

here is my app urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('', views.feed, name='feed'),
   path('', views.upload, name='upload'),
   path('', views.messages, name='messages'),
   path('', views.statistics, name='statistics'),
]
```

here is my project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from app.views import SendSmsCreateView
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
# ... your url patterns
path('', include('app.urls', namespace='app')),


url(
    regex=r'^app/$',
    view=SendSmsCreateView.as_view(),
    name='send_sms'
  ),

]
```

here is my index.html file

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<li class="nav-item">
        <a href=" {% static 'feed.html' %} " class="nav-link">
          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
          <p>
            Feed
            <span class="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
        <a href=" {% static 'messages.html' %} " class="nav-link">
          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
          <p>
            Compose Message

          </p>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
        <a href=" {% static 'upoad.html' %} " class="nav-link">
          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-chart-pie"></i>
          <p>
            Upload CSV
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

   </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was to add the namespace in the html file

before i used

```
 <a href=" {% url 'feed.html' %} " class="nav-link active">
```

the above didn't work so i changed it to

```
 <a href=" {% url 'app:feed' %} " class="nav-link active">
```

Answer (score 0):

some of the noticed faults are

context is missing in view, add an empty brackets as shown, which will server as context now, later on you can add key and values reqired

```
def index(request): 
     return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

fault in indexing url, need to add non over lapping regex patters

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('feed/', views.feed, name='feed'),
path('upload/', views.upload, name='upload'),
path('messages/', views.messages, name='messages'),
path('statistics/', views.statistics, name='statistics'),
```

change the url to path as it outdated

```
path('app/',
    view=SendSmsCreateView.as_view(),
    name='send_sms'
  ),
```